# Using PagedList without a RecyclerView

Tags: android, pagedlist

All the examples I have seen using the PagedList use it in conjunction with a RecyclerView. I have the scenario where I would like to use the Paging library but without any need for the UI. For example, I initially have a Recyclerview that does retrieve a list of data through the use of the PagedList that is bound to a PagedListAdapter. The user can then remove items on the list they don't want and save the list.

The problem is, that the list can be large and the user may not necessarily scroll through the entire list. When the user goes to save their choices, I need to run the query again a second time that generated the RecyclerView items, only this time, the items are handled either by my ViewModel or some other business object layer. The user could hit the back button and leave the screen where they initiated the saving. They could do this while the saving is not even finished. So the saving of this data must not be bound to the UI because once the activity or fragment is destroyed, the paging data will no longer be received.

All the examples I've seen use LiveData with an observer. Because the saving can take a long time depending on the number of items to be saved, retrieving all the records must be done in batches. According to the PagedList documentation, the load around method is supposed to load the next batch of records. I wasn't able to get this to work. So I have two problems. How do I avoid using LiveData to obtain the batched records and how do I get load around to load the next batch. Here is the code in my ViewModel:

```
fun getConnectionsFromDB(forSearchResults: Boolean): LiveData<PagedList<Connection>> {
    return LivePagedListBuilder(connections.getConnectionsFromDB(forSearchResults), App.context.repository.LIST_PAGE_SIZE).build()
}

fun storeGroupConnections(groupId: String, connections: PagedList<Connection>) {

    val groupConnections = mutableListOf<GroupConnection>()

    connections.forEach { connection ->
        if (connection != null)
            groupConnections.add(GroupConnection(groupId = groupId, connectionId = connection.rowid))
    }

    val disposable = Observable.fromCallable { groups.storeGroupConnections(groupConnections) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { },
            { ex ->
                App.context.displayErrorMessage(R.string.problem_storing_connections)
            },
            {
                connections.loadAround(groupConnections.size - 1)
            }
        )

    disposables.add(disposable)
}
```

And in my fragment:

```
fun storeGroupConnections(groupId: String) {
    connectionsViewModel.getConnectionsFromDB(args.forSearchResults).observe(this, Observer { connections ->
        groupsViewModel.storeGroupConnections(groupId, connections)
    })
}
```